# Crontab - Run a cronjob quarterly

Tags: cron

Can anybody give a pattern on how do i run a cron job on quarterly basis. These include the dates `March 31`, `June 30`, `September 30`, `Dec 31`.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

The simplest solution here would be to have two entries in your crontab--one for the `30`s and another for the `31`s, e.g.:

```
 0 0 30 6,9 * /path/to/your/script
 0 0 31 3,12 * /path/to/your/script
```

Comment: If his requirements did not state the specific dates, would 0 0 0 */4 * work?

Comment: @Navarr Almost--you'd need `0 0 1 */3 *` to get quarterly though (three months in a quarter, not 4).  I think 0 for the day-of month field is inconsistently supported, so use 1 for the first.  It might be more obvious to just list the months you want to to run, though.

Comment: @michael-c-oconnor My mistake.  Thanks for that!

Comment: @MichaelC.O'Connor i believe `0 0 1 */3 *` would run on the first day of the new quarter. I believe OP wanted the last day of the quarter.

Comment: @dopatraman, yes, it would.  That solution was in reference to an earlier comment asking about a quarterly job that did not require specific dates.  The main answer is the best solution I could find if we require the job to run on the dates the original question asked for.

Answer (score 7):

At 00:00 on day-of-month 1 in every 3rd month

0 0 1 */3 *

from https://crontab.guru/every-quarter

Comment: That works for the first day of the month every 3 months, not the last day of the month.